# How to force my template resolver to use ClassLoaderTemplateResolver for /mail/* templates

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using two template resolvers for my Spring Boot Application ServletContextTemplateResolver and ClassLoaderTemplateResolver.

I am using ServletContextTemplateResolver for /WEB-INF/* html templates for my web pages. I will on the other hand, use ClassLoaderTemplateResolver for my /mail/ html templates. Here's the code:

```
@Bean(name ="templateResolver") 
public ServletContextTemplateResolver getTemplateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new 
    ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("XHTML");
    templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(1));
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean(name ="emailTemplateResolver")    
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver getEmailTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new 
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(2));
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/mail/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver;
}
```

It shows the following error when calling the mail template:

> Resource resolution by ServletContext with
>   org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.ServletContextResourceResolver can only
>   be performed when context implements org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext
>   [current context: org.thymeleaf.context.Context]

How can I force it to use ClassLoaderTemplateResolver for /mail/* templates?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably rendering an html file and want to keep the resultant html file in a string variable which later you will be using it to email by using html to pdf conversion. So the following code will help you in Spring boot:

```
@Controller
public class jataController {

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @GetMapping(value = "/manual-thym")
    @ResponseBody
    public void justSample() {
        Context context = new Context();
        String filename = "templates/view/generated-ticket.html";
        String html = renderHtml(filename, context);
        System.out.println("template\n" + html);
    }

    private String renderHtml(String filename, Context context) {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        String html = templateEngine.process(filename, context);

        return html;
    }
}
```